06 Suzuki Forenza has error code p2101, p2110, p2135 whats the fix
My bf replaced all the parts that the shop stated it needed. Throttle body w/sensor, app sensor, battery. The car is in limp mode. Cleared codes after repair but still is like it didn't change anything. Could the ecm computer be bad? The weirdest thing is it does start on the first time but runs rough. 06 suzuki forenza 2.0L 4-cyl mt 84,000mi.
